# Item is being inserted twice (into both subtrees). cause is unknown

Tags: tree, prolog, insertion

I wrote a function that inserts an element into a tree, and then returns the new tree. It takes the form:

```
% insert(Element, OldTree, NewTree)
?-insert(2, tree(nil, 5, nil), T).
```

and, in theory, should return:

```
T = tree(tree(nil, 2, nil) 5, nil)
```

Simply put, the two is being added to the left subtree, and nils are added to make it binary. However, in my implentation, the two gets added to both left AND right subtree. The conditionals are always violated; if the 2 was a 6, it is still added to both subtrees, not just the right.

I've been going through this code for an hour, and cannot find the bug. Could a fresh pair of eyes skim through this?

```
tree(Left, Root, Right).

insert(Item, Oldtree, Newtree).

%tree is empty
insert(Element, Empty, tree(Empty, Element, Empty)):-!.

%tree isn't empty. if NewItem is less than Root, we put it on the left subtree
insert(NewItem, tree(LeftSubtree, Root, RightSubtree), tree(NewLeftSubtree, Root, RightSubtree)):-
        NewItem < Root,
    !,
        insert(NewItem, LeftSubtree, NewLeftSubtree).

%else
insert(NewItem, tree(LeftSubtree, Root, RightSubtree), tree(LeftSubtree, Root, NewRightSubtree)):-
    NewItem > Root,
    !,
        insert(NewItem, RightSubtree, NewRightSubtree).
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, don't do this:

```
tree(Left, Root, Right).
```

This defines `tree` as a (rather useless) predicate. You don't need to declare data types in Prolog.

Next,

```
insert(Item, Oldtree, Newtree).
```

defines `insert/3` as a predicate that will always succeed. You don't need this clause.

```
insert(Element, Empty, tree(Empty, Element, Empty)):-!.
```

doesn't do what you think it does; `Empty` is a variable, so it matches anything.

Finally, instead of all the complicated cut logic, use if-then-else:

```
insert(X, tree(L0,Y,R0), tree(L,Y,R)) :-
    (X < Y ->
        % insert into left subtree
    ; X > Y ->
        % insert into right subtree
    ;
        % equals case
    ).
```